# drupal 7: views filter on page id else show all

Tags: web, filter, drupal-7, drupal-views

I can't seem to figure it out on my own so.

My problem can be solved by using multiple views that do the same thing but I don't think that is efficient so. I have also found that it can be solved by taxonomy terms but I think that can cause problems after a while.

I have a slideshow as banner(same for all pages) now when you go to an event page you only should see the banners of that event (not all the banners like everywhere else) that's a simple filter write? But now to do this in one single view.

I tried a couple of things, the closest was to 
add a contextual filter on [content: Nid] and then provide default value: content ID from url, but how can I do this for just on the event pages?

(events is a content-type so the event pages are just content-type pages)

An online dev version is available on http://dev.runnersmovevents.be/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Quiet embarrassing "Action to take if filter value does not validate" i selected here display all and it works fine.